# How to force the page to reload when the hardware back button is pressed?

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova, jquery-mobile, back-button

I am developing a Cordova (PhoneGap) application using jQuery Mobile framework for Windows Phone 7. I'd like to get some pages refreshed/reloaded when the user hits the hardware back button. I am not using any data-rel="back" attribute.

How can I force the page to be reloaded when the user hits the hardware back-button?

Answer (score 1):

Listen to [the back button event](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#backbutton) and call the necessary code there. I'm not familiar with jQuery Mobile, but it seems like you could use [`changePage`](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/api/methods.html) with the `reloadPage` option set to `true`.

Comment: "backbutton" event does not seem to fire in WP. I tried it on Android, and it worked. Thank you, but I guess a different approach is necessary.

Comment: @burakk What version of WP are you using?

Comment: What version of PhoneGap? It looks like WP back button support was added in 1.6.0.

Comment: I'm using the latest version, 2.2.0